# Is it possible to see the MAC addresses of devices connected to other WIFI access points?

Tags: wifi, mac-address, nic

I'm aware that a NIC in promiscuous mode is able to detect packets of wifi enabled devices looking for networks and obtain their MAC addresses, is it still possible to obtain the MAC Address of a device connected to a wifi access point?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible when the AP is using WEP or no encryption at all. APs using WPA or WPA2 however will encrypt the whole header.

A WEP Wifipackage has the following structure:

[image: http://i.technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC196388.gif]

> Address Fields Depending upon the frame type, the four address fields
>   will contain a combination of the following address types: BSS
>   Identifier (BSSID). BSSID uniquely identifies each BSS. When the frame
>   is from an STA in an infrastructure BSS, the BSSID is the MAC address
>   of the AP. When the frame is from a STA in an IBSS, the BSSID is the
>   randomly generated, locally administered MAC address of the STA that
>   initiated the IBSS.
>
> **Destination Address (DA)**. DA indicates the MAC address of the final
>   destination to receive the frame.
>
> **Source Address (SA)**. SA indicates the MAC address of the original
>   source that initially created and transmitted the frame.
>
> **Receiver Address (RA)**. RA indicates the MAC address of the next
>   immediate STA on the wireless medium to receive the frame.
>
> **Transmitter Address (TA)**. TA indicates the MAC address of the STA that
>   transmitted the frame onto the wireless medium.

If you want to grab MAC addresses it would be possible to just sniff them from the packages sent in on the different Wi-Fi networks (Using WEP or No encryption).